# Django how to enter multiple records on one form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin, modelform

I am writing a calendar app with the following models:

```
class CalendarHour(models.Model):
    '''
    Each day there are many events, e.g. at 10 am, the framer orders
    material, etc.
    '''
    day_id = models.ForeignKey(CalendarDay)
    time = models.TimeField()
    work = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'work that took place at {work_time}'.format(work_time = self.time)

class CalendarDay(models.Model):
    '''
    Each project has so many daily logs.  But, each daily log belongs to     only one project (OneToMany relationship)
    '''
    company_id = models.ForeignKey(CompanyCalendar)
    day_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True) # Recording the date each log is entered in
    deadline = models.DateField() # The date for the daily log
```

Now, I want to create a form based on these models that has the information about the day, but 24 rows of entry instances, each representing one hour. So, in forms.py:
    #forms.py
    from django.forms import ModelForm

```
class HourForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = CalendarHour
        fields = ['entry_id', 'day_date', 'deadline']

class DayForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CalendarDay
        fields = ['company_id', 'day_date', 'deadline']

# In views.py:
...
class CalendarSubmit(View):
    template_name = 'calendar/submit.html'
    today_calendar = CalendarDay
    each_hour_calendar = CalendarHour

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form1': self.toady_calendar, 'form2':self.each_hour_calendar })

    def post(self, request):
        today = self.today_calendar(request.POST)
        each_hour = self.each_hour_calendar(request.POST)

        if today.is_valid():          
            today_calendar.save()

        if each_hour.is_valid():
            each_hour_calendar.save()
```

Now, I can show two different forms in the template, form_day and form_hour.  I can even repeat the form2 fields 24 times, but when it is posted, the first hour ends up in the database and the others are ignored.  I know in the admin, there is an add buttom that adds multiple instances, but I do not know how to achieve this in my case: how to display two relating models on one form where the referring model needs to be populated multiple times.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Daniel!  I'll read the documentation and will let you know if that takes care of it.

Comment: True, I think Django formsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/ fits your case

Comment: Thank you Daniel! I did the reading.  I still have a problem though.  When a user enters a time, Django throws an exception complaining that the input data is not of the type timestamp with time zone.  time_aware = pytz.timezone("Canada/Pacific").localize(event_datetime, is_dst = None) and instance.time = time_aware did not do the trick either!  Still the same error.  Any idea?